# Mobile Android Chrome not working great with HTML5 and CREATEJS - freezing issues

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-canvas, createjs

I have developed an app using HTML5 and CREATEJS. I am encountering some issues that I cannot find a solution, for weeks. I hope someone can help.

1)On Android Google Chrome there is a problem that appears when I simply click anywhere on the screen: the FPS drops and any animation that is playing freezes for the duration of my touch. The problem is only in Mobile Chrome browser, on Android. It does not exist in other mobile browsers, neither in iPhone, neither in Safari, Firefox, etc.
I created a simple apk using webview and it doesn't have the problem either. So for some reason, the problem is only in mobile android chrome.

The code is optimized at maximum. 2 months ago we used only 1 canvas, but now we use multiple canvases and we have less animations in each canvas running everytime. While in android firefox it works perfect, but in android chrome it freezes for a single click.

I tried to disable stagemousedown/up events, because they are being triggered when I simply click anywhere in the stage. This didn't fix the problem or it is possible that there are some hidden stagetouch events that I don't know how to disable.

2)On Android Google Chrome and iPhone6 Safari, when I click the SPIN button, the game starts the SPIN, but with a delay of at least 1.5 seconds, but there is no such delay added with intention inside the code. On PC any browser, Android/iOS Mobile Firefox, this works perfect, no delay. In iOS Safari iPhone8 again it works perfect.
I created a simple apk using webview and it doesn't have this problem either. So for some reason, the problem is only in mobile android chrome.
**UPDATE 11/10/19: Issue 2 has been solved by reducing canvas size and removing all shadow effects which consumed a lot of memory. Issue 1 still remains unsolved with absolutely no ideas left to try out. Any help is appreciated.**

My project is 99% completed except these 2 issues. I am hoping to be able to fix them, because I really do not want to throw away months of work and switch to other javascript library for gaming, that doesn't have the problem, like PIXIJS.

I tried with RAF and RAF_SYNCHED, but still no improvement in any scenario.
Stage.update() is required for any animation. Having them on ticker is the reason why its getting slower.

To see the problem in action, please open this URL: http://www.nevergone.biz/DEMO_CODE/index.html

How to test: Open the link above in Android Google Chrome portrait mode and then click SPIN. During SPIN click above the game canvas or anywhere. Notice that everything freezes.

The code was extracted only for testing these issues, so after a few spins it may freeze. I will fix this tomorrow, but I hope someone can give some ideas for solving the problem.

Comment: Maybe use an actual html5 game engine for developing your game. seems like its just optimization issues

Comment: The first point is working fine for me in Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @ArulMani what device did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem #1 is apparently isolated on some older devices that use Android Google Chrome. The problem is somehow caused by CREATEJS using too many listeners on the stagedown event.  I am currently waiting for the developer of the framework to give an answer or for Chrome to receive a serious update.

Problem #2 was fixed by removing all text-shadow CSS effects which apparently were consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: Is it CreateJS that "uses too many listeners", or your code? Is this referring to this issue? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1010022

Comment: @Lanny The problem is the same. I don't think it's from the personalised code that my team developed. It's some incompatibility between how CreateJS listens to touch events and how Chrome on Android handles them. On iOS, the problem doesn't exist, because on iOS Chrome uses Webkit. We also made a Webkit app for Android and the problem doesn't exist either. In Android Firefox, it also doesn't exist. So to isolate the issue, it seems to be an incompatibility between the Blink Engine (used by Chrome) and CreateJS. I also tested complex projects developed using Pixi on Android Chrome and no issue.

Answer (score 0):

cache might work.

```
var testShape=new createjs.Shape(); 
testShape.graphics.beginFill("red").rect(0,0,100,100);
testShape.cache(0,0,100,100);
stage.addChild(testShape); 

// If you make changes and want to refresh the cache
testShape.updateCache()
```